# fftwf_execute_dft_c2r writes the input buffer

Tags: c++, fftw

I have the following code:

```cpp
auto in = std::array<std::complex<float>, 60>();
in[0] = 10000.0f;
auto out = std::array<float, 100>();
auto plan = fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_2d(10, 10, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(in.data()), out.data(), FFTW_ESTIMATE | FFTW_UNALIGNED);
fftwf_execute_dft_c2r(plan, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(in.data()), out.data());
```

When I run it, my `in` array gets written (specifically the first column is set to 10000.0). Is this normal? Can I avoid the `in` array being written?

Comment: See [documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html) for `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT`

Comment: I see. No `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` for 2d c2r :(

Can't vote your answer though, because it's a comment. It did help me.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer, I'm too lazy to compose one, which is why I left a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data), the input data will be overwritten when using `c2r` transforms

> Second, the inverse transform (complex to real) has the side-effect of
>   overwriting its input array, by default. Neither of these
>   inconveniences should pose a serious problem for users, but it is
>   important to be aware of them.
>
> As noted above, the `c2r` transform destroys its input array even for
>   out-of-place transforms. This can be prevented, if necessary, by
>   including `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` in the flags, with unfortunately some
>   sacrifice in performance. This flag is also not currently supported
>   for multi-dimensional real DFTs (next section).

So even if `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` is used, it will not work in this case. From the [`FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html)

> `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` specifies that an out-of-place transform must not
>   change its input array. This is ordinarily the default, except for `c2r`
>   and `hc2r` (i.e. complex-to-real) transforms for which
>   `FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT` is the default. In the latter cases, passing
>   `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` will attempt to use algorithms that do not destroy
>   the input, at the expense of worse performance; for multi-dimensional
>   `c2r` transforms, however, no input-preserving algorithms are
>   implemented and the planner will return `NULL` if one is requested.

Hence, the easy way to solve this is just make a copy of the input array before passing it to the plan function.

Comment: Yep. I had come to the same conclusion.